# How to make sure Babel is working properly in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am getting up to speed with Aurelia.

I have a project set up and running based on the skeleton navigation project.

It starts up, and then tries to load welcome.js and then errors out.

It errors out on this line:

```
heading = 'Welcome';
```

If I change the line of code to

```
heading : 'Welcome';
```

Then it works.

So somehow, the ES6 classes do not seem to be loaded properly by babel.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `build\babel-options.js` file. It should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  modules: 'system',
  moduleIds: false,
  comments: false,
  compact: false,
  stage:2,
  optional: [
    "es7.decorators",
    "es7.classProperties"
  ]
};
```

The `es7.classProperties` line is the important one in your case.

Comment: This now works.  I added this following line to config.js which contains the jspm options, which includes a section for babel: `"babelOptions": {
      "optional": ["runtime","es7.decorators","es7.classProperties"]
  }`